# jQuery qtip: amend hover in order to include link in tooltip?

Tags: jquery, tooltip

I'm using [qtip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/) for jQuery tooltips, which is very good.

However, I can't work out how to fix the hover in order to include a link in the tooltip text.

By default, the tooltips vanish as soon as you stop hovering over the tooltipped element - so you can't move your mouse over the tooltip itself, in order to click on the link.

Anyone know a way round this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

**fixed: true** of **hide** option is intended to do that:

```
$('#content').qtip(
{
      content: 'This tooltip wont hide as long as mouse is over it',
      hide: { when: 'mouseout', fixed: true }
});
```

see http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/docs/reference/#hide-fixed for details

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could take a look at the [beforeHide](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/docs/api/#beforeHide) callback? If you return false in that callback, it will not be hidden, thus allowing you to include a clickable link in the tooltip.

Comment: You mean some logic like "beforeHide, check whether the mouse is still over the tooltip: if yes, don't hide"?

Comment: Sorry for the late response, but yes, that's what I mean.